# Unity, tell matched players to go pick characters (Matchmaking)

Tags: unity, multiplayer, matchmaking

I need to tell all the players in the match to go to some method that'd take them to character pick. The thing is that the pick happens inside the menu scene after the level get's preloaded (ascyncroneously). So the players stay in the same menu scene but they have to pick characters before the time runs out and the level itself starts. 
Is it possible to do that in multiplayer using the matchmaker?
How can it be done if so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: @ratchetfreak not really helpful, mate

Comment: That's why it's a comment. What issues are you getting when trying to implement this in multiplayer?

Comment: I'm also not clear on what specific obstacle you're trying to overcome here. Can you please edit your question to clarify what's gone wrong or where you've gotten stuck when you've tried this so far?

Comment: I assume youre familiar with the ClientRpc and Command annotations? If so, effectively the player that hasnt chosen, wouldnt have sent whatever `spawn character` command to the server, which means the server wouldnt have told the other clients to spawn that player avatar through the matching ClientRPC call. Could you elaborate on what you have so far, and what behavior you're seeing? Code samples tend to be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that in multiplayer using the matchmaker?

It sure is!

> How can it be done if so?

Essentially you have to create your own NetworkManager, if you look at the source of the default [NetworkManager](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/networking/src/2018.3/Runtime/NetworkManager.cs) or [NetworkLobbyManager](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/networking/src/5.3/Runtime/NetworkLobbyManager.cs) (Make sure you alter the branch to your Unity version) you'll find they are just using the [Network Messages](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetMessages.html) API to create the flow of creating players and moving scenes.

So for your custom network manager you would need to create a message:

```
public class GameMessageTypes
{
    public static short CharacterSelect = MsgType.Highest + 1;
}

public class CharacterSelectedMessage : MessageBase
{
    public int characterID;
    public int slotID; // Assuming you use the NetworkLobbyManager as a base, otherwise figure out your own slot system
    public bool isLocked;
}
```

then in both the client and server you would register to listen for it:

```
// In the server only register.
NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(GameMessageTypes.CharacterSelect, OnServerCharacterSelectInternal);

// In the client only register.
client.RegisterHandler(GameMessageTypes.CharacterSelect, OnClientCharacterSelectInternal);
```

You would ensure that you don't move \ load the next scene until all slots have selected a character or the timer to select has run out. In the server handler you would let other clients know of a clients selection and in the client handler you would update the UI \ view to show the player what the other players have selected.

One thing to note is that [UNET is getting deprecated:](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001252086-UNet-Deprecation-FAQ) 
[image: Unet Deprecation Timeline]

so you might want to look at your own system or use one of the forks of UNET that is community maintained like [mirror](https://github.com/vis2k/Mirror). If you go the route of your own system you should look at the [benchmark tests](https://github.com/nxrighthere/BenchmarkNet/wiki/Benchmark-Results) that a helpful community member made.

Comment: Since you've said that UNET is getting deprecated. What do you think about Photon instead?

Comment: I personally dislike photon, but it might be okay for your purposes.